# as3 - A button to round number decimal by decimal

Tags: actionscript-3, rounding, calculator

I need help. I want to make a button that round a number, decimal by decimal, like 1.2345 to 1.234 to 1.23 etc. I don't want to use Math.round since that rounds to a whole number, and i don't know if i can use *10/10, *100/100 and so, since i get different amont of decimals in my answer. This button will have to work on a calculator after i've clicked `btnEquals`and just round the answer.

I also need help to use `addEventListener` to a label in a "List" component.

Comment: So every time you click the button you want it to round one more place?

Comment: Also check if `yourNumber.toPrecision(x);` does what you want... Where `x` is amount of required digits after decimal point.

Comment: @NealDavis yes, that's what i mean

Comment: @E.Lil excuse my bad memory... It's `yourNumber.toFixed(x);` Where `x` is amount of required digits after decimal point. Your button should simply **-1** the value of variable `x` each time it's pressed. Try a simple test now and check with `trace` command...

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I've well understood the question, but in your case I 'd do something like this :

```
var myVal:Number = 1.2345
var vectorFloorResult:Vector.<Number>;
var vectorRoundResult:Vector.<Number>;
var decimals2String:String = myVal.toString();
var firstDecimal:uint = (decimals2String.lastIndexOf(".")+1);
var lastDecimal:uint = decimals2String.length;
var decimals: uint = (lastDecimal-firstDecimal)

var decimalsMultiply:uint = Math.pow(10,decimals);


trace ("decimals = " + decimalsMultiply)
// output : decimals = 4 

function decreseDecimals():void{
    vectorFloorResult = new Vector.<Number>()
    vectorRoundResult = new Vector.<Number>()
    for (var i:uint = decimalsMultiply; i>=10; i/=10){
        vectorFloorResult.push(Math.floor(myVal*i)/i)
        vectorRoundResult.push(Math.round(myVal*i)/i)
    }

}

decreseDecimals();

trace("floor result = " + vectorFloorResult);
trace("round result = " + vectorRoundResult);
```

Output :

```
decimals = 10000
```

For a Math.floor :

```
floor result = 1.2345,1.234,1.23,1.2
```

For a Math.round :

```
round result = 1.2345,1.235,1.23,1.2
```

You may change the code to get the results when you CLICK on a Button...

Sorry but My English is really bad!
So this is perhaps a wrong answer. :(

**TL; DR; more information's but it's boring!**

If you want to use a fixed vector length, you may change the function to:

```
function decreseDecimals():void{
    var count:uint = 0
    trace(lastDecimal)
    vectorFloorResult = new Vector.<Number>(decimals,true)
    vectorRoundResult = new Vector.<Number>(decimals,true)
    for (var i:uint = decimalsMultiply; i>=10; i/=10){
        vectorFloorResult[count]=(Math.floor(myVal*i)/i)
        vectorRoundResult[count]=(Math.round(myVal*i)/i)
        count++
    }

}
```

That's surely better if you thing about "performances"...

**Really too long, DR; ;)**

[EDIT]

To update a TextField or another component with the result, You may do this :

```
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.display.SimpleButton;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var myVal:Number = 1.2345;
var vectorFloorResult:Vector.<Number > ;
var vectorRoundResult:Vector.<Number > ;
var decimals2String:String = myVal.toString();
var firstDecimal:uint = (decimals2String.lastIndexOf(".")+1);
var lastDecimal:uint = decimals2String.length;
var decimals:uint = (lastDecimal - firstDecimal);
var myCustomButton:SimpleButton = myCustomButton;
var myDisplayRound:TextField = new TextField();
myDisplayRound.x = 100;
myDisplayRound.y = 50;
myDisplayRound.text = myVal.toString();
addChild(myDisplayRound);

var myDisplayFloor:TextField = new TextField();
myDisplayFloor.x = 100;
myDisplayFloor.y = 100;
myDisplayFloor.text = myVal.toString();
addChild(myDisplayFloor);
    var countClicks:uint = 1;
var decimalsMultiply:uint = Math.pow(10,decimals);
function decreseDecimals():void {
    var count:uint = 0;
    vectorFloorResult = new Vector.<Number > (decimals,true);
    vectorRoundResult = new Vector.<Number > (decimals,true);
    for (var i:uint = decimalsMultiply; i>=10; i/=10)
    {
        vectorFloorResult[count]=(Math.floor(myVal*i)/i);
        vectorRoundResult[count]=(Math.round(myVal*i)/i);
        count++;
    }
}
decreseDecimals();
myCustomButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,changeDisplay);
function changeDisplay(me:MouseEvent):void {
    myDisplayRound.text = vectorRoundResult[countClicks].toString();
    myDisplayFloor.text = vectorFloorResult[countClicks].toString();
    if (countClicks < vectorRoundResult.length-1)
    {
        countClicks++;
    }
    else
    {
        countClicks = 0;
    }
}
```

[/EDIT]

Comment: PS: The logic you put here would be appreciated on the [**`Math`**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/math) and even the [**`Javascript`**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tags. I suggest you follow them even if those Questions are in other coding Languages. Logic of Answer is still useful without code...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129635/discussion-between-tatactic-and-vc-one).